# Accessing the Task_Struct CPU Time Parameters Linux

Tags: c, linux, kernel, cpu-usage, kernel-module

I am trying to edit the way the badness score is implemented in the `Linux OOM Killer`. I am trying to write my own system call.

I am having trouble figuring out where I obtain the task_struct that is being passed in `unsigned long badness(struct task_struct *p, unsigned long uptime)`. I need to use the s->utime and s->stime from task_struct and I have no idea how to access it.

In my code:

```
#include <linux/timex.h>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>

void CPU(void)
{
    printk("Total CPU Time.\n");
    struct task_struct *p;

    cpu_time = (cputime_to_jiffies(p->utime) 
               + cputime_to_jiffies(p->stime))>> (SHIFT_HZ + 3);

    printk(cpu_time);
}
```

Link with [`OOM-Killer`](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/mm/oom_kill.c#L598).

Comment: in `linux/sched.h`, also from www.cs.fsu.edu:  there is a global variable `extern struct task_struct init_task`  try to start with that, using the macro `do_each_thread` as in http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/mm/oom_kill.c#L209